# global variable in R function

Tags: variables, r, function

I created a function for processing some of my data, like this:

```
a <- "old" 
test <- function (x) {
   assign(x, "new", envir = .GlobalEnv)
} 
test(a)
```

But I can't see the a change from "old" to "new", I guess this is some of the "global variable", any suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: First of all, don't do it -- messing in a global environment with functions is almost always a bad idea leading to random overwrites, hard to track bugs and overall chaos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

for `assign(x,value)`,x need to be a name of a variable not value of it, so x should be in character form: `assign("a","new")`,and in order to be used in your function,try:

```
test <- function (x) 
{
  assign(deparse(substitute(x)), "new", envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
```

in your case, you will creat a variable named "old" and assign "new" to it:

```
> old
[1] "new"
```

Answer (score 2):

you could combine your function with the `sapply` function,
eg:

```
require (plyr)
b <- sapply (a, test)
b
  old 
"new"
```

that way you are applying your function to the actual elements of your `a` vector - as romunov pointed out in his answer.

another eg:

```
a <- c("old", "oold", "ooold", "oooold")
b <- sapply (a, test)
b
   old   oold  ooold oooold 
 "new"  "new"  "new"  "new"
```

Comment: which one is the plyr function?

Comment: @Stephen: oh yeah, right. `sapply` is from the base package - corrected that. the plyr function are always named with one 'p'.